# Is it possible to call a 'remote_function' method in helper file instead of controller using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3. I am trying to use the `remote_function` and I would like to call a method from my helper instead of the controller.

So, in my view file I have:

```
<%= 
    f.text_field :name, :id => "name_id",
      :onkeyup => remote_function(
        :update => "name_div",
        :url => { :action => :method_name }
%>
```

That, actually, will call the following method from the controller file (I properly set routers, as well):

```
def method_name
  ...
end
```

I would like to move the `method_name` code in my helper file and then call that method from the helper instead of controller (without setting router). **Is it possible using `remote_function`? If so, how to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use remote_function to call a helper method directly. All remote_function does is generate some JavaScript that can make an Ajax request to a particular URL (from the client side). For that URL to work, the route and controller action have to be set up to respond to it.

If your goal is to move the code out of the controller, you could put the action method into a module and include that module in one or more controller classes. You would still need the routes set up to point to that method/action in each controller, however.